# Surface view Black Screen Home Button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am developing one app where just show clouds walking through the screen using surface view everything gone good until push the Button "HOME BUTTON" so when i returned to my app just showing screen in black, the rest of the app works fine just is when you push the "Home Button"

Where is my Code for the surfaceView

```
      import android.content.Context;
      import android.graphics.Bitmap;
      import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
      import android.graphics.Canvas;
      import android.graphics.Color;
      import android.graphics.Paint;
      import android.util.AttributeSet;
      import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
      import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class mysurfaceview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


private  mysurfaceviewThread bbThread = null;

private int xPosition = (getHeight()/2);
private int yPosition = (getHeight()/2);
private int posicion2 = (getWidth()/2)-40;
private int posicion3 = (getWidth()/4);
private int xDirection = 1;

public mysurfaceview(Context ctx,AttributeSet attrs){
    super(ctx, attrs);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

public void doDraw(Canvas c){
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myimage);
    c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.drawBitmap(icon, xPosition, yPosition, new Paint());
    c.drawBitmap(icon,posicion2,(getHeight()/2),new Paint());
    c.drawBitmap(icon,posicion3,(getHeight()/2)+40,new Paint());
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    if (bbThread!=null) return;
    bbThread = new mysurfaceviewThread(getHolder());
    bbThread.start();
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){
}

public void surfaceDestroyed (SurfaceHolder holder){
    bbThread.detener();
}


public class mysurfaceviewThread extends Thread{
    private boolean corriendo,pausa;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    public mysurfaceviewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    }

    public synchronized void pausar() {
        pausa = true;
    }

    public synchronized void reanudar() {
        pausa = false;
        notify();
    }

    public void detener() {
        corriendo = false;
        if (pausa)
        reanudar();
    }

    public void run(){
       corriendo=true;
        while(corriendo){
            xPosition+=xDirection;
            posicion2+=2;
            posicion3+=1;
            if(xPosition==getWidth()){
            xPosition = -200; }
            if(posicion2==getWidth()){
                posicion2 = -200; }
            if(posicion3==getWidth()){
                posicion3 = -200; }
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                doDraw(c);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder){
                }
            } finally {
                if(c != null) surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);}
            synchronized (this) {
                while (pausa) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public mysurfaceviewThread getThread(){
    return bbThread;
}
```

}

Here is the code for Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class animadofondo2 extends Activity{

private mysurfaceview Clouds;
private mysurfaceview.mysurfaceviewThread CloudsThread;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sufeaviewfondo);
    Clouds= (mysurfaceview ) findViewById(R.id.ViewsLaynubes);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Clouds.getThread().pausar();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Pausa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    Clouds.getThread().reanudar();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Restart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



@Override protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onResume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Nubecitas.getThread().pausar();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Lamar(null);
    finish();
}


public void Lamar (View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, main.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

Here is the XML for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.app.example.proyectsurface.mysurfaceview
    android:id="@+id/ViewsLaynubes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```